# In Eclipse how do I remove old or not needed class files from SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

When I first started my current project.  I went our SVN Repository. I created a new branch off the trunk.  Then I copied an existing branch, a previous version of my current project to the new branch. Then I imported the project in to Eclipse.

Now that my current project is close to being complete. I have quite a few class files not being used in the new project.  But the files are still part of the Repository.

What I am trying to figure out, is how can I remove the files from my project.  So that the latest version of my project, does not show them any longer.  I don't want to delete the files from the Repository, just from the latest revision.

Example:

Project - Revision 1

Class A
Class B
Class C
Class O - Old
Class U - Old

Want to delete files and commit

Project - Revision 2

Class A
Class B
Class C

But if something horrible happened and I needed the files back, I would like to be able to do a revert to revision 1

Class A
Class B
Class C
Class O - Old
Class U - Old

Commit to Revision 3

It was suggested to me to -> right click the file -> team -> delete
I do not see the delete option in the team menu.

Can I just,  right click the file -> delete -> team -> commit -> make sure to check them in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have correctly set up Eclipse with a Subversion client plug-in like Subclipse, and it recognizes that your project exists within a working copy, it will handle the `svn rm` task for you automatically when you delete the file from the project tree view.

If you really want to be sure, drop to a command line and run `svn rm <file>`.

I would recommend removing all `.class` files (and any other built artifacts) from your repository, and setting up `svn:ignore` rules to prevent them from being added in the future. It's not necessary to version these, since you are already versioning everything needed to rebuild them.